# Application on systems of equations

Tags: equation-solving

Lauren has 20 coins in her piggy bank, all dimes and quarters. The total amount of money is $3.05. How many of each coin does she have?

Answer (score 2):

A perfect place to use `FindInstance`:

```
FindInstance[n1*10 + n2*25 == 305 && n1 + n2 == 20, {n1, n2}]
{{n1 -> 13, n2 -> 7}}
```

So Lauren has 7 quarters and 13 dimes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a linear Diophantine equation in two variables: $10x+25y=305$. Generating functions give the number of solutions for coin change problems like this. For example,

```
GFCoinPartitions[n_, d_List]:= Block[{z}, 
   Coefficient[Series[Product[1/(1-z^d[[i]]), {i,1,Length[d]}], {z,0,n}], z, n]]
```

where`n`is the total to find, 305 pennies in this case, and`d`is a list of coin denominations, 10 and 25 in this case. There are 6 solutions to this problem. The ever popular`FrobeniusSolve`finds them by using:

```
FrobeniusSolve[{10, 25}, 305]
(* {{3, 11}, {8, 9}, {13, 7}, {18, 5}, {23, 3}, {28, 1}} *)
```